# How to properly align a page with header, nav, section and footer // HTML5 and CSS

Tags: css, html, alignment

Im trying for some while already to properly align my page. In jsfiddle it seems to be looking nice, but in my widescreen monitor the section tag floats all the way to the left and makes a big mess!
I think I'm doing something wrong with the floating... But still: this is an exercise from my course and it says that i NEED to use the sections as display:block and align them with floating.

I've been stuck in this for a good while and I my course tutors dont answer!
Hope somebody can show me where I'm being mistaken.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header class="menu">
        <a href="index.html"><img class="imglogo" src="img/TotalLogo.png"></a>
    </header>
    <section class="apres">
        <p>Para&iacuteso dos Nerds</p>
        <img src="img/Personagens.png">
        <p>Jogos, Consoles, Acess&oacute;rios e Figuras de A&ccedil;&atilde;o</p>
    </section>            
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Total Control</a></li>
            <li><a href="consoles.html">Consoles</a></li>
            <li><a href="jogos.html">Jogos</a></li>
            <li><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
            <li><a href="compras.html">Compras</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <footer class="ender">
        <p>Av. Irm&atilde;os M&aacute;rio, 234<br>
            Tel: (21) 1234-5678<br>
            <a href="mailto:contato@tecontrol.com.br">contato@tecontrol.com.br</a>
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}
body {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #4466AA;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana, Liberation;

}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;

}
a:visited{
    color:#0000FF;
}
a:link{
    color:#0000EE;
}
.menu{
    color:#0000EE;
    list-style-image:url(img/cogumelo.png);
    width:170px;

    line-height:50px;

}
.ender{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top:15px;
    border-top:3px solid;
}
.apres{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.imgLogo{
    border-bottom:2px solid;
}

/* Header, nav, section e footer */

header{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
nav{
    display:block;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
}
section{
    display:block;
    width:540px;
    float:right;

}

footer{
    clear:both;
}

nav li:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    background: #E2E2E2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

The link to jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/67jrj/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of your page to what you like, 960px is a good standard. Create a div for each element needed to float in an area then clear the float with the next area. Also, rearrange the order of your elements in your html so they appear as you need them to. I'm including my example of your page, at least what I think your asking. :)

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Total Control</a></li>
        <li><a href="consoles.html">Consoles</a></li>
        <li><a href="jogos.html">Jogos</a></li>
        <li><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
        <li><a href="compras.html">Compras</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="apres">
    <p>Para&iacuteso dos Nerds</p>
    <img src="img/Personagens.png">
    <p>Jogos, Consoles, Acess&oacute;rios e Figuras de A&ccedil;&atilde;o</p>
</div>

<div class="ender">
    <p>Av. Irm&atilde;os M&aacute;rio, 234<br>
    Tel: (21) 1234-5678<br>
    <a href="mailto:contato@tecontrol.com.br">contato@tecontrol.com.br</a>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #CCCCCC;
color: #4466AA;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, Liberation;
margin: 0 auto;
width:960px;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
display:block;

}
a:visited{
color:#0000FF;
}
a:link{
color:#0000EE;
}
.menu{
color:#0000EE;
list-style-image:url(img/cogumelo.png);
width:170px;
float:left;
line-height:50px;

}
.ender{
text-align:center;
font-size:16px;
padding-top:15px;
border-top:3px solid;
clear:both;
}
.apres{
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;

width: 350px;
margin: auto;
}
.imgLogo{
border-bottom:2px solid;
}

/* Header, nav, e footer */

.header{

display:block;
margin-bottom:15px;
width:960px;
}
.nav{
display:block;
width:240px;
float:left;
}

nav li:hover{
color:#FFF;
background: #E2E2E2;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
padding-right:3px;
padding-left:3px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set standard width for header, section(s) and footer, or better, wrap them all in a div, assign a class to it and set margin to that class. There's nothing called "root" element, replace that with html (that is what they mean by root element).

Comment: root is probably a type for `:root`. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/